# How many times should i run computer simulations to conclude one experiment in netlogo?

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I am working on a model in netlogo which is a statistical physics based model. How many times should i run the simulation and average the results to conclude the study?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156080/how-many-simulations-need-to-do/29192802#29192802

Comment: There is no universal number that fits all.I assume you mean how many times you need to run same simulation (same parameters) with different random seeds. I usually do my experiments with at least 20-30 different random seeds for each parameter combination. For my experiments that gives me just enough confidence interval. @JenB answer gives you better idea.

Answer (score 1):

As Marzy points out in comments, there is no definitive answer. Many people will pick the magic numbers 20-30 out of a hat and go with that. A common choice is to do a small number (5-10) runs initially, estimate the variance from them, and then project how large a sample size you would need to bring the margin of error (half-width of the confidence interval) down to some desired tolerance.